# Java SSHJ - Add to known_hosts file in verifier

Tags: java, ssh, sshj

I am using SSHJ to execute a remote command, which I can successfully do when the host is in the SSH `known_hosts` file. However, if the host is not in this file then I would like to the the user the option to add it.

I believe the way to do this is to create a custom `HostKeyVerifier` (template shown below). However I am struggling to convert the `PublicKey` into the `AAAAB3Nz...cTqGvaDhgtAhw==`  format to enable me to append the host into the `known_hosts` file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public class CustomVerifier implements HostKeyVerifier {

    public boolean verify(String hostname, int port, PublicKey key) {

        System.out.println(key);    
        System.out.println(KeyType.fromKey(key));
        System.out.println(key.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println(key.getEncoded());
        System.out.println(key.getFormat());

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the key from `known_hosts` is done using the following code (See: OpenSSHKnownHosts.java line 213):

```
key = new Buffer.PlainBuffer(Base64.decode(sKey)).readPublicKey();
```

This means that if you have a key, you need to do the reverse:

```
keyString = Base64.encodeBytes(new Buffer.PlainBuffer().putPublicKey(key).getCompactData());
```

Or even better, you can extend the `OpenSSHKnownHosts` class and override the `hostKeyUnverifiableAction`, similar to how `ConsoleKnownHostsVerifier` does it.